# Simple query to join with my booking table without duplicating records for each booking

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a customer credit table and a booking table, shown below.  I've executed the following query which works but it's too simple.  I now need to cross join my original query to the booking table so I can check for where the booking status is completed.  My second query is wrong because it SUMs the adjustment for each booking.

**Initial working query**

```
select customer_id, SUM(adjustment) from customer_credit group by customer_id;
```

**Query with join**

```
select c.customer_id, SUM(c.adjustment) 
from customer_credit c 
inner join booking b 
on b.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.customer_id;
```

**Customer credit**

```
| id | customer_id | adjustment | 
| 1  | 1234567     | 50         |
```

**Booking**

```
| id | status    | customer_id |
| 1  | completed | 1234567     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the sum first and then `join`:

```
select c.customer_id, c.adjustments, b.*
from (select c.customer_id, sum(c.adjustment) as adjustments
      from customer_credit c 
      group by c.customer_id
     ) c left join
     booking b 
     on b.customer_urn = c.customer_id;
```

Note:  I suspect that you might want a `left join` to handle customers with no adjustments.

Comment: Trying this returns ERROR:  column c.adustments does not exist

Comment: you can change "c join" to "c left join"

Comment: @Jack . . . That was a typo.

Comment: and then the filter gets appended to the end (status = 'completed')?

Comment: @Jack . . . You would not use a `left join` in that case, but that is how you would see only the completed bookings.

Comment: I can see the customer_id multiple times? I need the results to be distinct for each customer

Comment: perhaps "select c.customer_urn" on the first line becomes "select distinct(c.customer_urn)"

Comment: @Jack . . . Ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Join to the result of the first query:

```
select c.customer_id, c.total_adjustment, b.id, b.status
from (
  select customer_id, 
         SUM(adjustment) total_adjustment 
  from customer_credit 
  group by customer_id
) c 
  join booking b on b.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

Comment: Trying this I get missing FROM-clause entry for table "c"

Comment: @Jack: sorry, typo with the alias (replace `cc` with `c`)